# How to use the Top Charts feature of Google Trends from a Node JS based application

Tags: node.js, google-trends

I'm creating a `Node.JS` based application which can pick various trending topics from Google Trends by using the [google-trends](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-trends-api) npm package. I have a requirement to fetch results like `most searched actors` or `most searched movies` for a particular year in a specific country.

Currently, the google-trends package provides the below-mentioned methods

- autoComplete
- interestOverTime
- interestByRegion
- relatedQueries
- relatedTopics

Unfortunately, none of these methods is able to give what I'm looking for. If I search with a keyword for `top actors`, it's only giving how many times this keyword was searched over time, region and related queries and topics like that.

If I go to the [Top Charts](https://trends.google.com/trends/topcharts) window, I can see the list of trending actors, movies, songs and stuff like that. But there is no direct way to get these results via a NodeJS application.

If anyone could help me resolve this issue, it'll be a big help.